# How to sort python dictionary by values in descending order. If two values are same then sort items lexicographically?

Tags: python

```
dictionary={'b': 5, 'a': 2, 'k': 5}
```

The correct output should be: dictionary={'b': 5, 'k': 5, 'a': 2}

Used the following approach:

```
sorted(dictionary.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
```

but the output is coming as `{'k': 5, 'b': 5, 'a': 2}`

edit1: I am using Python 3

Comment: note that depending on your python version `dict`s are not sorted and you may need to use https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict .

Comment: Which Python version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your python version may not keep the order in which you entered your key-value pairs. In which case you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.OrderedDict)

```
from operator import itemgetter
from collections import OrderedDict

dictionary={'b': 5, 'a': 2, 'k': 5}

s = OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items(), key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True))
print(s)
# OrderedDict([('b', 5), ('k', 5), ('a', 2)])
```

if your python version is <= 3.5 dicts will lose their order; in python 3.6 the order-keeping is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied on. [starting from python 3.7 this is considered](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html) to be part of the language specification.

so starting from python 3.7 your code will not need `OrderedDict` and you can work with the regular `dict`.